# Optimal High-Density Binary Space Partition for Grids

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm writing a game in which a character moves around on a randomly generated map in real time (as it's revealed.) This leads me an interesting data structures problem. The map is generated as it comes into view, in a circle around the character (probably 20-60 tiles) so where there is data, it is very dense, and all in a grid. Where there's not data, though, there could be huge, ungenerated spaces. The character could walk in a huge circle, for example, creating a ring of tiles around vast empty space.

A simple matrix would create massive amounts of unneeded overhead, and waste a lot of space. Typical BSPs, though, seem like they would cause a huge performance drop because of the dense, grid-like nature of the data.

What do you suggest? Matrixes - quadtrees - some hybrid of the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been tackling this for the past month, and have come up with what I believe is a fairly good solution. It's not as fast as a pure matrix, but has the benefit of being infinitely extensible (within the limits of an `int`.)

Basically, it's a binary space partition which builds upwards (instead of downwards, like a quadtree.) If you write to a point outside of the currently allocated matrix space, it generates a larger node and expands. If a majority of a node's children nodes are allocated matrices, it will aggregate them into itself and remove their references. This means that the more well-defined boundaries you use, the better performance you get, as the more this structure acts like a matrix.

I've posted my code [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/832464/Code/MatrixSpacePartition.cs), and will try and write some sort of demo in the future, and move to a better hosting site.

Don't hesitate to let me know what you think, or if you have any questions about it.

Comment: As your sample code is not commented, I did not really looked at it much... From what you are describing an extremely simple solution comes to mind. Partition your landscape to matrices and use relative coordinates (to actor) to retrieve data. That way you will only generate/retrieve data of 4 matrices at most while the other ones are uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking of implementing something similar in my game that I am working on. I'm going to create a custom class that can be accessed like a 2D array ex. `map[x][y]` but the underlying datatype would be closer to a hashtable. Something like `data[x.Value.ToString() + "," + y.Value.ToString()]`

My game is fairly basic as my tiles will only ever be walkable, deadly, or unwalkable.

I'm interested in a more elegant solution though :D

Comment: You have the right idea.  You define a custom class that has the properties and methods you need to model a standard 2D array of 40 x 40 tiles.  As the character moves near (< 5) the next standard 2D array, you load the next standard 2D array.

Comment: Originally, I did something like that. I had a `Dictionary<PointF, T>` Everything worked fine, except for retrieving elements from the dictionary, which took way too long. Perhaps a better structure could be used in the same manner, but I fear a hybrid quadtree-matrix is in order...