# Efficiently copying a matrix of objects to a larger matrix of objects

Tags: c#

I'm writing a quadtree-like data structure which contains matrices of generic objects `T`. If four subnodes all contain defined matrices of `T`, I'm going to aggregate them into a single, larger matrix, then delete the subnodes. Is there a more efficient way to do this than looping through every reference and copying it over? Can I copy chunks of memory instead?

---

**Example:**

```
T[,] _leaf1 = new T[64,64];
T[,] _leaf2 = new T[64,64];
T[,] _leaf3 = new T[64,64];
T[,] _leaf4 = new T[64,64];

// Populate leafs

T[,] _root = new T[128,128];

CopyInto(ref _root, ref _leaf1, 64, 64);
CopyInto(ref _root, ref _leaf2, 0, 64);
CopyInto(ref _root, ref _leaf3, 0, 0);
CopyInto(ref _root, ref _leaf4, 64, 0);
```

Comment: How do you reprent the matrices exactly? Aggregate how? If the items are reference types, you are just copying a pointer (4/8 bytes), which if pretty fast. There are only 4 (lists of) items there, right?

Comment: I added an example. In my structure, `_leafX` would be in a child node, with `void CopyInto(ref T[,], Point p)`

Comment: So in other words: you are copying the elements of a matrix to some other matrix? You can use `Array.CopyTo` or a `Buffer.BlockCopy` (copying will only take several µs). Also, if you modify your design so it is not `array[64]`, but `array[64*64]` and use modulo (`%`) to check rows, it will be even faster. Not sure where your performance bottleneck is though. It depends how often you access the elements of the matrices vs. how often you copy.

Comment: btw. you are doing the opposite of what a QuadTree is doing. QT is splitting, your are composing.

Comment: I know, but I'm not sure what else to call it. In the end, you end up with a quadtree-like structure.

Comment: @Daniel: Why don't you tell us what you want at the higher level of abstraction - maybe there are better ways to solve your problem than matrices and copying...

Comment: I've finished the structure I was working on. I just stuck with iterative copying of each reference. If you'd like to comment on my class, you can find it on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142919/optimal-high-density-binary-space-partition-for-grids/3379594#3379594

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make the structure immutable, you can perhaps save yourself from having to make lots of copies. Eric Lippert has some [great posts about immutable structures](https://ericlippert.com/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability/).

Edit:
Again, I don't know if it will improve performance in your case, but here is an example of a possible design with immutable objects:

```
abstract class QuadTree<T>
{
    public QuadTree(int width, int height)
    {
        this.Width = width;
        this.Heigth = heigth;
    }

    public int Width { get; private set; }
    public int Height { get; private set; }

    public abstract T Get(int x, int y); 
}

class MatrixQuadTree<T> : QuadTree<T>
{
    private readonly T[,] matrix;

    public QuadTree(T[,] matrix, int width, int heigth)
        : base(width, heigth)
    {
        this.matrix = matrix;
    }

    public override T Get(int x, int y)
    {
       return this.matrix[x, y];
    }
}

class CompositeQuadTree<T> : QuadTree<T>
{
    private readonly QuadTree<T> topLeft;
    private readonly QuadTree<T> topRight;
    private readonly QuadTree<T> bottomLeft;
    private readonly QuadTree<T> bottomRight;

    public CompositeQuadTree(QuadTree<T> topLeft,
        QuadTree<T> topRight, QuadTree<T> bottomLeft,
        QuadTree<T> bottomRight)
        : base(topLeft.Width + topRight.Width, 
            topLeft.Height + bottomLeft.Heigth)
    {
        // TODO: Do proper checks.
        if (this.Width != topLeft.Width + bottomRight.Width)
            throw Exception();

        this.topLeft = topLeft;
        this.topRight = topRight;
        this.bottomLeft = bottomLeft;
        this.bottomRight = bottomRight;
    }

    public override T Get(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x <= this.topLeft.Width)
        {
            if (y <= this.topLeft.Width)
            {
                return this.topLeft.Get(x, y);
            }
            else
            {
                return this.topLeft.Get(x, y + this.topLeft.Heigth);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (y <= this.topLeft.Width)
            {
                return this.topRight.Get(x + this.topLeft.Width, y);
            }
            else
            {
                return this.topRight.Get(x + this.topLeft.Width, 
                    y + this.topLeft.Heigth);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you would be able to use it as follows:

```
T[,] _leaf1 = new T[64,64];
T[,] _leaf2 = new T[64,64];
T[,] _leaf3 = new T[64,64];
T[,] _leaf4 = new T[64,64];

// Populate leafs

QuadTree<T> l1 = new MatrixQuadTree<T>(_leaf1,64,64);
QuadTree<T> l2 = new MatrixQuadTree<T>(_leaf2,64,64);
QuadTree<T> l3 = new MatrixQuadTree<T>(_leaf3,64,64);
QuadTree<T> l4 = new MatrixQuadTree<T>(_leaf4,64,64);

// Instead of copying, you can no do this:
QuadTree<T> c = CompositeQuadTree<T>(l1,l2,l3,l4);

// And you can even make composites, of other composites:
QuadTree<T> c2 = CompositeQuadTree<T>(c,c,c,c);

// And you can read a value as follows:
T value = c2[30, 50];
```

Again, I don't know if it is appropriate in your situation or whether it gives an performance improvement, because you have a level of indirection when getting the value. However, there are several ways to improve this, but it depends on what you really need to do.

Good luck.

Comment: If I understand the OP's neeeds correctly, there may already be some data in the root matrix, you would simply overwrite them. But maybe it is the solution he's looking for - it depends on his needs. He's not really using a `QuadTree`, just a simple matrix.

Comment: It is of course hard to tell whether this is what he needs. I just gave an direction that might be interesting to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am way off base here, but if you constrain `T` to be a reference type then you would be copying nothing more than the references and not the data itself. So just create new references to the `T` objects in the new matrix and remove them from the old matrices. Here is how you can constrain `T`. Notice the use of the `where` and `class` keywords.

```
public class Foo<T> where T: class
{
}
```

Comment: A very good point, and I could restrict the generic to objects if need be, but this still requires looping through every pointer to be copied.

Comment: *@Brian*  The point is to find a solution which doesn't require looping. I'm away that for classes, I'm not copying the entire object's data.

Answer (score 0):

[System.Buffer.BlockCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) perhaps?  That'll copy chunks of memory.

Comment: How can I use BlockCopy on a matrix? It only takes arrays, and `Matrix[C]` errors.

Comment: Jaroslav built some sample code around my suggestion, I'm just going to follow up with comments at his answer.

Comment: @Ben: Actually I have suggested `BlockCopy` in my comments to OP's answer so I built it around those comments to be precise.

Comment: @Jaroslav: My answer was here 14 minutes before your comment, but I admit that since .NET only provides a couple ways to copy memory chunks around that you likely already knew about `BlockCopy` and didn't take the idea from me.  Nevertheless when you are elaborating on an idea that someone else mentioned first, it's considered polite to mention their answer.

Comment: @Ben: It's possible. I could not edit my comment so I had to delete and copy-paste it again (maybe there is another option? I am still new to SO)... Later decided to make it to a full answer anyway. I'll add you to "credits" on next edit if it is needed.

Comment: @Jaroslav: No worries.  Like I said, BlockCopy is THE function for doing this in .NET so it's no surprise that multiple people independently suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't afraid to use unsafe code and you could uses references, you can use old style pointers. You have to use the `fixed` keyword to your arrays at first.
Multidimensional array aligns each dimension after each other.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to put my comment as an answer.

So in other words: you are copying the elements of a matrix to some other matrix? You can use `Array.CopyTo` or a `Buffer.BlockCopy` (copying will only take several µs).

Also, if you modify your design so it is not `array[64]`, but `array[64*64]` and use modulo (`%`) / multiply (`*`) to get/set elements, it will be even faster. Not sure where your performance bottleneck is though. It depends how often you access the elements of the matrices vs. how often you copy.

```
public class Matrix<T>
{
    private int size;
    private T[] elements;

    public Matrix(int size)
    {
        this.size = size;
        this.elements = new T[size];
    }

    T this[int x, int y]
    {
        get
        {
            return elements[x + (y*size)];
        }
        set
        {
            elements[x + (y*size)] = value;
        }
    }

    public void CopyTo(Matrix<T> destination, int x, int y)
    {
        int offset = x + (y*size);
        T[] destinationArray = (T[])destination;
        Buffer.BlockCopy(this.elements, 0, destinationArray, offset, this.elements.Length);
    }

    public static explicit operator T[] (Matrix<T> matrix)
    {
        return matrix.elements;
    }
}
```

and in code:

```
Matrix<int> leaf = new Matrix<int>(64);
Matrix<int> root = new Matrix<int>(128);
leaf.CopyTo(root, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would actually work... Consider a 2x2 matrix `[[1,2][3,4]]`, stored as an array `(1,2,3,4)`. There would be no way to copy it into a 4x4 matrix directly, since `[1,2]` and `[3,4]` would need to be split. It looks to me as if your method would make the first row of the larger matrix `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Yes, you'll have to copy row by row, but you can at least copy an entire row at once instead of having to copy individual elements.

Comment: @Daniel: It would, but you can setup the matrices to be composites of other matrices and change the indexer. 2x2 would look like `elements[1,2,3,4]` and 4x4 `elements[1,2,3,4,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,...]`. So the offset 0 to 3 represents the first submatrix. etc. or simply copy row by row :)