# Optimizing quadrant selection

Tags: c#, optimization, bit-manipulation

I'm working on a data structure which subdivides items into quadrants, and one of the bottlenecks I've identified is my method to select the quadrant of the point. Admittedly, it's fairly simple, but it's called so many times that it adds up. I imagine there's got to be an efficient way to bit twiddle this into what I want, but I can't think of it.

```
private int Quadrant(Point p)
{
    if (p.X >= Center.X)
        return p.Y >= Center.Y ? 0 : 3;
    return p.Y >= Center.Y ? 1 : 2;
}
```

`Center` is of type `Point`, coordinates are `ints`. Yes, I've run a code profile, and no, this isn't premature optimization.

---

Because this is only used internally, I suppose my quadrants don't *have* to be in [Cartesian order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Quadrants_and_octants), as long as they range from 0-3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way in C/C++ it would be

```
(((unsigned int)x >> 30) & 2) | ((unsigned int)y >> 31)
```

(30/31 or 62/63, depending on size of int).
This will give the quadrants in order 0, 2, 3, 1.

Edit for LBushkin:

```
(((unsigned int)(x - center.x) >> 30) & 2) | ((unsigned int)(y-center.y) >> 31)
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account an arbitrary centerpoint around which to construct quadrants.

Comment: I've finished the structure I was working on. Thanks for your comment, but I wasn't able to get the time down too significantly, so I stuck with my original implementation. If you'd like to comment on my class, you can find it on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142919/optimal-high-density-binary-space-partition-for-grids/3379594#3379594

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that you can make this code dramatically faster in C#. What you may be able to do, however, it look at how you're processing points, and see if you can avoid making unecessary calls to this method. Perhaps you could create a `QuadPoint` structure that stores which quadrant a point is in (after you compute it once), so that you don't have to do so again.

But, admittedly, this depends on what your algorithm is doing, and whether it's possible to store/memoize the quadrant information. If every point is completely unique, this obviously won't help.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been told about the solution which produces 0,1,2,3 quadrant results ordered correctly:

```
#define LONG_LONG_SIGN (sizeof(long long) * 8 - 1)

double dx = point.x - center.x;
double dy = point.y - center.y;

long long *pdx = (void *)&dx;
long long *pdy = (void *)&dy;

int quadrant = ((*pdy >> LONG_LONG_SIGN) & 3) ^ ((*pdx >> LONG_LONG_SIGN) & 1);
```

This solution is for x,y coordinates of double type.

I've done some performance testing of this method and the method with branching as in original question: my results are that **the branching method is always a bit faster (currently I am having stable 160/180 relation)**, so I prefer the branching method over the method with bitwise operations.

---

**UPDATE**

If someone is interested, all three algorithms were merged into [EKAlgorithms C/Objective-C repository](https://github.com/EvgenyKarkan/EKAlgorithms) as "Cartesian quadrant selection" algorithms:

1. Original branching algorithm
2. Bitwise algorithm by @ruslik from the accepted answer.
3. Alternative bitwise promoted by one of my colleagues which is a bit slower than second algorithm but returns quadrants in correct order.

All algorithms there are optimized to work with double-typed points.

Performance testing showed us that **in general the first branching algorithm is the winner** on Mac OS X, though on Linux machine we did see second algorithm performing a small bit faster than the branching one.

**So, general conclusion is to stick with branching algorithm because bitwise versions do not give any performance gain.**

Answer (score 0):

My first try would be to get rid of the nested conditional.

```
int xi = p.X >= Center.X ? 1 : 0;
int yi = p.Y >= Center.Y ? 2 : 0;
int quadrants[4] = { ... };
return quadrants[xi+yi];
```

The array lookup in quadrants is optional if the quadrants are allowed to be renumbered. My code still needs two comparisons but they can be done in parallel.

I apologise in advance for any C# errors as I usually code C++.

---

Perhaps something more efficient is possible when two unsigned 31 bit coordinates are stored in a 64 bit unsigned long variable.

```
// The following two lines are unnecessary
// if you store your coordinated in unsigned longs right away
unsigned long Pxy = (((unsigned long)P.x) << 32) + P.y;
unsigned long Centerxy = (((unsigned long)Center.x) << 32) + Center.y;

// This is the actual calculation, only 1 subtraction is needed.
// The or-ing with ones hast only to be done once for a repeated use of Centerxy.
unsigned long diff = (Centerxy|(1<<63)|(1<<31))-Pxy;
int quadrant = ((diff >> 62)&2) | ((diff >> 31)&1);
```

---

Taking a step back, a different solution is possible. Do not arrange your data structure split into quadrants right away but alternately in both directions. This is also done in the related [Kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree)

Comment: I doubt this would be much faster. You doing the same number of conditional checks, but you're also adding an array lookup. The code may be more concise, but you'd have to profile it to prove it's faster.

Comment: int xi = (int)(p.X >= Center.X);
int yi = (int)(p.Y >= Center.Y) * 2; 

dirty way?

Comment: @arul: You cannot cast a `bool` to any numeric type in C#. This won't compile.

Comment: @arul That shouldn't make any difference with enabled optimization if changed to a compiling version.